# Where does SecKeyCreateSignature get the key name for Keychain signing authorization dialog?

Tags: swift, macos, keychain

I have noticed a difference between certain keys in the Keychain with respect to how they appear in the Keychain signing dialog, and I cannot figure out why some are displayed a certain way while others are not.

Here is some test code to use identities in the Keychain to sign a sample bit of data.

```swift
 func testCreateSignature() throws {
        
        let query: [String: Any] = [kSecClass as String: kSecClassIdentity,
                                    kSecMatchLimit as String: kSecMatchLimitAll,
                                    kSecReturnAttributes as String: false,
                                    kSecReturnRef as String: true,
                                    kSecReturnData as String: true]
        
        var resultsRef: CFTypeRef?
        let status = SecItemCopyMatching(query as CFDictionary, &resultsRef)
        guard status == errSecSuccess else { throw SecurityError.unhandledError(status: status) }
        
        
        guard let results =  resultsRef as? [[String:Any]] else {
            throw SecurityError.unexpectedCertificateData
        }
        
        let data = Data([0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF])
        var privateKey: SecKey!

        for result in results {
            
            let secIdentity = result[kSecValueRef as String] as! SecIdentity
            
            try SecIdentityCopyPrivateKey(secIdentity, &privateKey).check()
            
            var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
            let signature = SecKeyCreateSignature(privateKey, .rsaSignatureMessagePKCS1v15SHA1, data as CFData, &error)!
            if let error = error {
                throw error.takeRetainedValue()
            }

            print(signature)
        }

        
    }
```

When the code attempts to use one of the keys that Xcode installed for code signing, the resulting dialog looks like the following:

[image: signing with Apple private key]

However, when the code attempts to use a key that I've installed, no matter what the label on the key in the Keychain is, it always looks like this:

[image: signing with other private key]

When my app attempts to use a key to sign, I would like the user to see the name of the key the app wants to use, instead of just generic "privateKey", but I cannot find where this information might be stored on the key.

I have checked the `kSecAttrLabel` and `kSecAttrApplicationLabel` attributes of both identities and the private keys and cannot find the text that appears in the dialogs.

Comment: I believe the above one is created by using a *certificate* instead of a *private key*. I'm not too sure about the signing process of an application, but I believe you create a CSR using a certificate or create a certificate as CA. In either case, the above one likely derives the name from a certificate field, instead of a key field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. It is a property of the Access Control List of a Keychain item. See ['descriptor' param for SecAccessCreate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1393522-secaccesscreate).

If you do not specify a custom ACL when importing a key, it will default to "privateKey".

I was using [SecPKCS12Import](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1396915-secpkcs12import) to import a `.pfx` file. I attempted to set the `kSecImportExportAccess` key in the `options` parameter to a custom `SecAccess` object, but it would always import with a default ACL.

I ended up refactoring the code to use [SecItemImport](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1395728-secitemimport) instead to import the `.pfx` file and supplied a custom `SecAccess` instance:

```swift
    static func importIdentity(contentsOf url: URL, password: String) throws {
        
        let data = try Data.init(contentsOf: url)
        
        var access: SecAccess!
        try SecAccessCreate("License Key" as CFString, nil, &access).check()
        
        var keychain: SecKeychain!
        var outItems: CFArray?
        let filename: CFString? = url.isFileURL ? url.lastPathComponent as CFString : nil
        var inputFormat: SecExternalFormat = .formatPKCS12
        var itemType: SecExternalItemType = .itemTypeAggregate
        let unmanagedPassword = Unmanaged<AnyObject>.passRetained(password as AnyObject)
        let unmanagedAccess = Unmanaged<SecAccess>.passRetained(access)
        
        var params: SecItemImportExportKeyParameters = SecItemImportExportKeyParameters(version: UInt32(SEC_KEY_IMPORT_EXPORT_PARAMS_VERSION),
                                                      flags: .importOnlyOne,
                                                      passphrase: unmanagedPassword,
                                                      alertTitle: nil,
                                                      alertPrompt: nil,
                                                      accessRef: unmanagedAccess,
                                                      keyUsage: nil,
                                                      keyAttributes: nil)

        try SecKeychainCopyDefault(&keychain).check()
        try SecItemImport(data as CFData, filename, &inputFormat, &itemType, [], &params, keychain, &outItems).check()
   }
```

Importing the identity as above will result in "License Key" being shown in the signing dialog rather than "privateKey".